# Unable to remove the unmet dependencies or broken packages in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 dual boot with windows 10. While installing any programs it show me error like you have unmet dependencies. so i try many thing like :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install -f
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
dpkg --configure -a
```

But not working. when i try `sudo apt-get upgrade` it show error like

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcogl20 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgbm1 (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
 xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

sudo apt-get -f install give me error like :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcogl20 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
 libegl1-mesa : Depends: libgbm1 (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
 xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: Please run this first: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt update`, next `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: run & post `apt-cache policy libgbm1`